Gazebo headless rendering when running from python API
First of all, I apologize if my question is basic. I am a fairly new to gazebo and still learning. I couldn't find an answer in tutorials, docs, gazebo GitHub, this forum, gazebo answers/community or anywhere else online.
I am using gazebo harmonic on Ubuntu (22.04) to run .sdf defined worlds. I use the python (3.10) API to run the server as described in the tutorial:
https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/python_interfaces.html
I would like to take advantage of the headless rendering for the sensors as described in the tutorial:
https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/headless_rendering.html
Headless rendering works fine when running from terminal (--headless-rendering flag) but I wasn't able to find any way to use this when running the server from python API. Is there a way to achieve this?
